# Почему неисправно работает перевод из двоичной в десятичную?

Tags: c++, строки, системы-счисления

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void adding_null(std::string &bin_str)
{
    std::string nulls;
    while(size(bin_str) + size(nulls) != 7)
        nulls += '0';

    nulls += bin_str;
    bin_str = nulls;
}

void from_ten_to_two(int &num)
{
    int ans = 10;
    while (num > 0)
    {
        ans += num % 2;
        ans *= 10;
        num /= 2;
    }
    num = 0;
    while (ans > 0)
    {
        num += (ans % 10);
        num *= 10;
        ans /= 10;
    }
    num /= 100;
}

int main()
{
    long int key_int{0};
    std::string key_str;
    std::string key;
    std::cin >> key;

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        int dec = key[i];
        from_ten_to_two(dec);
        std::string bin = std::to_string(dec);
        adding_null(bin);
        key_str += bin;
    }

    std::cout << key_str << '\n';

    for(int j {0}, i{55}; i >= 0; i--, j++)
    {
        key_int += (key_str[j] - '0') * pow(2, i);
    }

    std::cout << '\n' << key_int << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Код должен переводить слово в двоичную, а затем в десятичную системы счисления. В key_str записано двоичное число из 55 символов 0 или 1, перевод должен осуществляться по формуле *101101102 = (1·27)+(0·26)+(1·25)+(1·24)+(0·23)+(1·22)+(1·21)+(0·20) = 128+32+16+4+2 = 18210* и записываться в key_int, но при переводе у некоторых чисел добавляется лишняя единица в конце.

Comment: У КАКИХ КОНКРЕТНО? Как вы задаете строку? Чтобы скомпилировать ваш код и воспроизвести ошибку... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: А у вас 55  бит в `key_int` вообще влазят? Это точно 8-байтовое число? Кстати, `pow(2, i)` — число нецелое... Что-то у вас какой-то наверченный код, в котором сложно разобраться, с "магическими константами" a la 55...  Скажите, в чем сверхзадача? Что ***должна*** делать программа?

Comment: @Harry пробовал вписывать ```unsigned long key_int``` и все равно не работает, ```pow()``` нецелое, но ведь число 2.0 будет 2 в int, некоторые слова считаются нормально

Comment: Я не знаю, какой у вас компилятор, посмотрите что выводится при `cout << sizeof(key_int);`

Comment: Задача принимает набор из 8 букв английских букв, переводит этот набор в двоичную, а затем в десятичную систему счисления

Comment: Как переводит? По какому правилу `xyztoief` должно превратиться в число?

Comment: ```cout << sizeof(key_int);``` выводит 8

Comment: Тогда с размером вопрос снят, его достаточно.

Comment: Код буквы из utf-8 переводится в двоичное число, эти двоичные числа становятся в один ряд и переводятся в одно большое десятичное

Comment: Поскольку utf-8 для английских букв ничем не отличается от ascii, то его упоминать не будем. Т.е. вы просто получаете 64 бита (кстати, первый символ — это старшие 8 битов или младшие?), и должны эту строку как двоичное и десятичное число — что сделать? Вывести? Записать в `string`?

Comment: Код берет строку zhonmong, берет побуквенно с первой буквы до последней, к примеру берет букву z, далее ее номер в таблице 122 записывает в ```int dec``` , переводит в двоичное число 1111010 и добавляет эти числа в строку ```key_str``` и так далее, потом эту строку переводит в десятичную, но неправильно, у набора букв babazina в конце лишняя 1 прибавляется, например

Comment: Да не нужно это все в строку переводить вообще! У вас же сама строка из 8 символов и есть **число**.

Comment: не нужно в одну строку ```key_str``` или какую? мне же их нужно в одно большое число соединить и перевести это большое число

Comment: перевод в двоичную осуществляется правильно, и сложение в один ```key_str``` тоже, но перевод в десятичную ```key_int``` выполняется некорректно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам все эти танцы с бубном не нужны. Не уверен во всяких stricted aliasing, но работать вполне будет:

```
string s;
cin >> s;
if (s.size() != 8)
{
    cerr << "Wrong length\n";
    return 1;
}
unsigned long long x = *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned long long*>(s.c_str());

// Если в обратном порядке:

reverse(s.begin(),s.end());
unsigned long long y = *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned long long*>(s.c_str());

cout << hex << x << "  " << y;
```

Специально не стал брать `bitset`, хотя с ним было бы проще.

Какое вам именно число надо — где первый символ старший или младший — выберите сами. Отличие в лишнем `reverse`.

А дальше просто выводите, как хотите, и что хотите, то и делайте.

https://ideone.com/pF6lDX

Comment: как работает ```*reinterpret_cast<const unsigned long long*>(s.c_str());```?

Comment: Воспринимает байты в вашей строке как байты 8-байтового целого числа.

Comment: как этот код полностью выглядит, чтоб его можно было скопировать и разобраться?

Comment: По ссылке в ответе полностью работающий код.